# React Material-UI : stacked appbar

Tags: meteor, reactjs, material-ui

Strange behaviour, when I try to make an appbar with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

// Needed for onTouchTap
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
injectTapEventPlugin();

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
                <div>
                    <AppBar title="Title"/>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>

        );
    }
}
```

The result gives me a stacked appbar:

[image]

I have absolutly no idea why it does that and did not find any similar issue. I am running on a fresh Meteor instance with React and Material-UI installed via `meteor npm install material-ui`

**EDIT:** After investigation, it seems the problem is that the appbar does not have `display:flex`. Yet, it is impossible to add it manually with `style={{display:'flex'}}` (nothing changes).

Comment: Strange behaviour: when I try the responsive layout and refresh the page via Chrome inspector, it suddenly works. It still does not work with normal layout after a refresh though.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but in case anyone sees this, the way to do this is to nest a `<Toolbar />` inside the `<AppBar />`.

[`<AppBar />` docs](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/)

Comment: Yeah well, this was for an older version of MUI but thanks for your answer, I am sure it might help people with the newer versions :)

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty fix: `<AppBar title="Title" className="appBar" />`

And in main.css:

```
.appBar{
    display:flex;
}
```

Weird behaviour though.